# In Daggerfall, where can I get mithril?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-ii-daggerfall

I've been encountering some daedra and other creatures in dungeons -- my steel dai-katana isn't cutting it any more. I know that you need **dwarven or better** for enemies like harpies, and **mithril or better** for daedra.

So, where can I get mithril? I've explored a variety of weapon shops (in the province of Daggerfall) and haven't come across it so far!

Comment: The depths of Khazad-dûm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly, what material a weapon or armor is made from is level dependent for drops. Raise a few levels and you should start to see better stuff. Also, (again, iirc) if you go into a weapon or armor shop, wait for it to close, and steal everything/sell it back a few times, the newer stock will be of better materials eventually including daedric.